# Start a java Minecraft Server on Windows using ProcessBuilder

Tags: java, process, minecraft, processbuilder

I have a class ServerStart.
When I try to start the Minecraft Bukkit Server nothing happens. 
The Process `server.waitFor();` returns 1, but I don't know what that means.
I believe it may be a permissions issue.

Console output:
1
java.lang.ProcessBuilder@7852e922
Error: Could not create the Java Virtual Machine.
Error: A fatal exception has occurred. Program will exit.
Invalid maximum heap size: -Xmx1024M -jar C:\Users\robio\Desktop\serverConsole\server.jar
Exited with error code : 1

```
public class ServerStart {

    private File serverFolder = new File("C:/Users/robio/Desktop/serverConsole/");
    private ProcessBuilder pb;
    private Process server;
    private BufferedReader reader;
    private String line;
    private int exitCode;

    public ServerStart() {
        init();
    }

    private void init() {

        if(serverFolder.exists() && serverFolder.isDirectory()) {
            System.out.println("1");
        }else {
            System.out.println("-1");
        }


        try {
            pb = new ProcessBuilder("Java", "-Xmx1024M -jar " + serverFolder + "\\server.jar");
            //pb.redirectOutput(serverFile);
            System.out.println(pb.inheritIO());
            server = pb.start();
            reader = new BufferedReader(
                    new InputStreamReader(server.getInputStream()));
            while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
                System.out.println(line);
            }

            exitCode = server.waitFor();
            System.out.println("\nExited with error code : " + exitCode);

        }catch(IOException | InterruptedException arg0) {
            arg0.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    public Process getServerProcess() {
        return server;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new ServerStart();
    }

}
```

Comment: First try to run manually using java -jar server.jar, if it works, execute the same command in the code.

Comment: I try it and it works but the console output is the same and it happend nothing

Comment: It's possible the process is emitting errors that will provide more information, but you need to read from the error stream in order to know.

Comment: pb.inheritIO() return this:1
java.lang.ProcessBuilder@7852e922
Error: Could not create the Java Virtual Machine.
Error: A fatal exception has occurred. Program will exit.
Invalid maximum heap size: -Xmx1024M -jar C:\Users\robio\Desktop\serverConsole\server.jar

Exited with error code : 1

Comment: Try `new ProcessBuilder("java", "-Xmx1024M", "-jar", serverFolder + "\\server.jar")`.

Comment: Oh thank it works but it has one problem. the Serverfiles are in my eclipse workspace xD how do they put it in the server folder? :D

Comment: Okay i got it completly thanks for the fast help :D  pb.directory(serverFolder);